# How to apply multiple effect on same element

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styles, effects

How can i set mulitple effect like(shadow and blur) on same element.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [Using Effects in WPF (Part 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/greg_schechter/using-effects-in-wpf-part-2) by Greg Schechter where one can simply nest `Decorators` like a `Border` and put a different `Effect`s on each.

Comment: Nice workaround for yet another WPF deficiency. Wish I knew what they thought when they decided not to implement an EffectGroup...

Comment: Simple yet effective.

Comment: The problem is, for complicated hierarchies, this applies the effect to the wrong items -- even just using a `Grid`, whether you put it above the control, inside the control, or as a sibling to the control, none of those gives the same result as applying the effect directly to the control in question.

Answer (score 5):

To build on the initial answer and provide an example, just enclose the `UIElement` within another new `UIElement` (any element for that matter, like a stack panel for example).

Then apply effects for both elements as such:

```
<StackPanel>
    <MediaElement Name="myMedia" Source="Fairytale Dream.wmv" >
        <MediaElement.Effect>
            <ShaderEffectLibrary:BloomEffect />
        </MediaElement.Effect>
    </MediaElement>
    <StackPanel.Effect>
        <ShaderEffectLibrary:ZoomBlurEffect />
    </StackPanel.Effect>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is in essence the same approach as the one that was credited to Greg Schechter, as accepted as answer. You could elaborate on how this differs, and/or refer to the other answer as it is so much alike.

Answer (score -7):

I think there is no need to combine effects here.

One of these effect will help you for simulating other effects
like in case of DropShadow Effect, You could use BlurRadius for Blur Effect and ShadowDepth for shadow..

By using appropriate values you could simulate combination effects...

Comment: It is not up to us to decide what the OP wants, especially since he clearly states what he's trying to achieve.