# .NET Framework 4 in WPF not showing bitmap effect

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am having a problem using VS2010 and framework version 4 with bitmap effects. If I have the code below and run it in a WPF application using the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, the bitmap effect does not appear. If I set the framework version to .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile (and change no code), it runs as expected. At first, I thought it was a problem in my application, but I removed the code and put it in a separate standalone application and it behaves the same. Anyone else verify that the same problem happens?

What is happening here?

The version 4 framework in VS2010 just seems to ignore the bitmap effect.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SectionHeaderTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen"/>
        <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Black"  GlowSize="3" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="Contact Details" Style="{DynamicResource SectionHeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As stated by others already: .NET 4.0 no longer supports BitmapEffects.

As an additional info: Since there is no `OuterGlowEffect` which you can use with the `Effect` property (at least none that I am aware of), you can replace the bitmap effect with a [`DropShadowEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.aspx) and set its [`ShadowDepth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.shadowdepth.aspx) property to 0. Then you can create a glow effect by adjusting the [`BlurRadius`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.blurradius.aspx) property. Furthermore, you can also adjust the [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.color.aspx) property if you want the glow to have another color than black, but as I see from your code sample, you actually use black as the `GlowColor`.

I know this workaround might not be as flexible and comfortable as the `OuterGlowBitmapEffect` and it does not produce identical results, but at least it comes close in some situations, and it is definitely easier than writing a pixel shader yourself...

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this as the answer because you also correctly noticed that the OuterGlowEffect is no longer supported and suggested an alternative.

Comment: +1: just as a side note: setting the BlurRadius to 0 or -1 will give you something similar but you will not achieve the same look as if you were using the OuterGlowBitmapEffect

Comment: That's true. And that's what I tried to say with *"might not be as flexible"*. Will edit my answer to be more precise.

Comment: Have assigned DropShadowEffect assigned to Effect property, how can I assign one more effect to it?

Comment: @LoveRight: This is another question, but [this answer might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801851/how-to-apply-multiple-effect-on-same-element). In short: It is not possible like with the `BitmapEffect` property, but there is a workaround for it. See the link for details.

Answer (score 4):

As stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743435.aspx) by Microsoft, `BitmapEffect` is obsolete as of .NET 4. Try using `Effect` instead.

Answer (score 3):

BitmapEffects are no longer supported in .NET 4.0.

You should use the Effect property instead.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743435.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-for-performance-in-wpf-in-net-4.aspx):

> **5. The BitmapEffect classes are now no-ops.**
>   BitmapEffect used to render
>   in Software and caused perf issues.
>   BitmapEffect are still there so your
>   apps will compile but BitmapEffect
>   will not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Bitmap Effects](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/wpf-workings/873-bitmap-effects.html) which explains some of the issues in using the new GPU based effects.